# What is this box of wires?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

Does anyone know what this small box of wires are? Seems to have a bunch of potential ground wires gathering here. The box itself is just screwed to the house. Some wires go to the telco box, one to the power meter, one into the house directly.

Seems outdated and wondering if it still serves a purpose and could maybe be removed? Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like old fashioned telephone service to me. Not sure, just saying.

Comment: I thought the same. Old telco box of some sort. I assume these are low voltage, if any at this point. I know it’s not the smartest to assume when it comes to electrical.

Comment: The OP added another pic after i commented.   Looks like a wire to the meter base is used as a ground.  the other wires (cables?) look like one is going to the gray box under the MB, which is probably the delineation (what do they call it?  can't remember: maybe network interface????)  .  One of the cables probably goes to the gray box and the other goes into the house connected to POTS wiring.   UV to zack

Comment: Old telco wiring was 48V, so still exciting to get a shock from.

Comment: I think this is a lighting arrestor or static discharge thingy for old telephone service.

Comment: Do you have a land line into your house? Most of this old telephone stuff has been changed out.

Comment: Someone was extending the Phone service. What is that box under the electricity meter ?

Comment: it's a POTS demarcation box ... without the box

Comment: If you have ADSL internet (or a 'land line' phone) then this *might* still be in use. If it is used by ADSL, then you *might* see a small speed improvement by getting that wiring mess cleaned up & covered to protect it from the weather..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is old bell telephone wire. The dial tone voltage if active won’t hurt but the ringer voltage is painful.
This is how land lines were wired prior to voice over IP (internet protocol) many homes this is no longer even used as the phone is bundled on the cable line if there is a land line at all.